# Rudin. Principles of Mathematical Analysis. Theorem 9.24

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is theorem 9.24 (Inverse Function Theorem) correct?

In (49)-(50) he shows that the mapping is a contraction. But it's a contraction of an open ball into an open ball. That is not a complete metric space.

Update: the theorem is below. The part I'm not sure is in italic.

**Theorem** Suppose $f$ is a continuously differentiable mapping of an open set $E \in R^n$ into $R^n$, $f'(a)$ is invertible for some $a \in E$, and $b=f(a)$. Then exists open sets $U$ and $V$ in $R^n$ such that $a \in U$, $b \in V$, $f$ is one-to-one on $U$, and $f(U)=V$.

**Proof**

Put $f'(a)=A$ and choose $\lambda = \frac{1}{2\|A^{-1}\|}$.

Since $f'$ is continuous at $a$ exists an open ball $U \in E$, which center at $a$ such that

$\|f'(x) - A\| < \lambda$ for $x \in U$

For every $y \in R^n$ put $\phi(x) = x + A^{-1}(y-f(x))$ for $x \in E$.

$\phi'(x) = I - A^{-1}f'(x) = A^{-1}(A-f'(x))$ then $\|\phi'(x)\| < \frac{1}{2}$. Hence, because $U$ is convex we get $|\phi(x_1) - \phi(x_2)| \le \frac{1}{2}|x_1 - x_2|$. *Then $\phi(x)$ is a contraction and has a fixed point in $U$, so that $f(x)=y$ for at most one $x \in U$.*

Comment: Please post the theorem in question.

Comment: Please, make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem is correct as written. All Rudin has shown is that the map is a contraction, so that there is *at most one* fixed point of the map $\varphi$. Indeed, if $\varphi(x) = x$ and $\varphi(y) = y$ for two different points $x\ne y$, then $|x-y|>0$, so $|x-y|=|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)| \le \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$, which is clearly impossible.

You noticed, however, that if the claim were *there is a fixed point*, then the space would have to be complete. For this purpose, it would suffice for the set in question to be closed. Since the set in question is open, it may well not be complete.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see it. So he shows that there is at most one point in U and not exactly one point?

Comment: @ilya Exactly. He is proving (a), which is that $\mathbf f$ is 1-1 on $U$, so this accomplishes that goal.